# WSO2 API manager - How to send Error/Fault message back to the Client from InSequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have created a REST API using WSO2 API Manager (StockQuoteService) and  configured a back end SOAP based web service (converting REST to SOAP) from where it will be getting the data based on the URL template.

In the "In Sequence", I have used a Switch mediator to send the request to different back end endpoints based on incoming data whereas in the default scenario (when no case match), I want to send the error message back to the client that the "Input message is invalid".

I have tried using the Send mediator, Respond Mediator, Sequence Mediator but still no success (may be doing something wrong) as still I am getting "no response from server" error when I try to invoke the URL which doesn't match any case of Switch and goes to Default.

How can I send the Error/Fault message back to the client from In Sequence of WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, the input sequence I used the switch mediator  and I invoke an operation or another, in the default option I create my failure response

```
  <inSequence>
     <switch xmlns:xsd="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd"
             description=""
             source="//xsd:desc">
        <case regex="NATURAL">
           <log description="Search Pharmacy" level="custom" separator=",">
              <property name="STATUS" value="Search Pharmacy"/>
           </log>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <p:searchpharmacy xmlns:p="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                    <ax22:pharmacy xmlns:ax22="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                       <xs:desc xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$1</xs:desc>
                       <xs:id xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$2</xs:id>
                       <xs:latitude xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$3</xs:latitude>
                       <xs:longitude xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$4</xs:longitude>
                    </ax22:pharmacy>
                 </p:searchpharmacy>
              </format>
              <args>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:desc"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:id"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:latitude"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:longitude"/>
              </args>
           </payloadFactory>
           <header name="To" scope="default" value="urn:searchpharmacy"/>
           <log level="full" separator=",">
              <property name="Mensaje" value="Cuerpo"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <case regex="EXPERIMENTAL">
           <log description="Search Pharmacy Direction" level="custom" separator=",">
              <property name="STATUS" value="Search Pharmacy Direction Request"/>
           </log>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <p:searchPhone xmlns:p="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                    <ax22:pharmacy xmlns:ax22="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                       <xs:desc xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$1</xs:desc>
                       <xs:id xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$2</xs:id>
                       <xs:latitude xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$3</xs:latitude>
                       <xs:longitude xmlns:xs="http://pharmacy.arce.org/xsd">$4</xs:longitude>
                    </ax22:pharmacy>
                 </p:searchPhone>
              </format>
              <args>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:desc"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:id"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:latitude"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//xsd:longitude"/>
              </args>
           </payloadFactory>
           <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:searchPhone"/>
           <property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" type="STRING" value=""/>
           <log level="full" separator=",">
              <property name="Data" value="Body"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <default>
           <log description="Fault" level="custom" separator=",">
              <property name="STATUS" value="Invoke fault "/>
           </log>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <rs:fault xmlns:rs="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
                    <rs:code>-1</rs:code>
                    <rs:type>Invocation error</rs:type>
                    <rs:message>No operation has been invoked</rs:message>
                    <rs:description>The value of the input parameter is not valid</rs:description>
                 </rs:fault>
              </format>
              <args/>
           </payloadFactory>
           <respond/>
        </default>
     </switch>
  </inSequence>
```

Here is the default section

```
<default>
   <log description="Fault" level="custom" separator=",">
      <property name="STATUS" value="Invoke fault "/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <rs:fault xmlns:rs="http://pharmacy.arce.org">
            <rs:code>-1</rs:code>
            <rs:type>Invocation error</rs:type>
            <rs:message>No operation has been invoked</rs:message>
            <rs:description>The value of the input parameter is not valid</rs:description>
         </rs:fault>
      </format>
      <args/>
   </payloadFactory>
   <respond/>
</default>
```

And the fault response

```
  {"fault":{"code":-1,"type":"Invocation error","message":"No operation has been invoked","description":"The value of the input parameter is not valid"}}
```

You can find other scenarios here

http://harshcreationz.blogspot.com/2016/02/common-and-error-handling-sequences.html

Comment: Hi Alber, Thanks for the reply. Actually when I am configuring this as you specified in the Default Section of Switch, it still is trying to invoke the backend URL. WIth WSO2 ESB, it works as expected, but with WSO2 API Manager, it still tries to hit the backend url and always gives the "No response from error" message.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
      <format>
          {
            "error":"true",
            "message":"error case"
          }
      </format>  
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<respond/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually I tried this, but it doesn't specify anywhere that it has to invoke the Fault Sequence, so after running this , it still tries invoking the backend URL (SOAP based Web Service). Is it possible somehow that in Default Case, we configure an error message or  invoke a Fault Sequence which prevents it from invoking the backend url and just display the configured fault message back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Nits
The error response as comments "no response from server", I receive it when I call the api from the test console that has the API Manager.

You can see this link
[API Console Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767675/api-console-issue)

To validate the response you expect.

Try calling from another tool such as SOAP UI or Postman, in my case I receive a fault response message with the structure defined.

This is the call from the console API

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 465f1385-a120-3c19-ad22-c3057e744a3b' 'https://169.254.193.10:8252/getById/1.0.0/getEmployeeXML?Id=5'
```

For the call from another client in the header pass these values you have in the api call

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 465f1385-a120-3c19-ad22-c3057e744a3b'
```